# Deleting values when the user closes the application

Tags: android, android-preferences

So in my application I am using `SharedPreferences` to save fragment state. But I would like to delete those entries inside the `SharedPreferences` once the user steps outside of the application. I tried the following:

In my main class:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    if(isFinishing() == true)
    {
        SM.removePreferences();
    }
}
```

where SM is an instance of a helper class I created. removerPreferences does the following:

```
public void removePreferences(){
    editor.clear();
    editor.commit();
}
```

But I noticed that this was never executed. With the log, I did see that the app goes inside the isFinishing() if statement, but the method is never executed. I also did try the `onDestroy()`, but the method never got called.

Can someone help me on this ?

Comment: `app goes inside the isFinishing() if statement, but the method is never implemented`.  If the code steps into the `if` block, then the method MUST be executed.  What makes you say that it is not?  BTW, logcat is not a good way to troubleshoot problems like this.  Instead, you should be using the debugger.  That's what it's for.  Also, shared preferences is not a good way of storing state that you will delete when the app exits.

Comment: How do you suggest that i'd do this saving states thing ... because it sort of was my last resort @Simon

Comment: "How do you suggest that i'd do this saving states thing" -- since it is unclear what the "states" are or why you are "saving" them, that is impossible to answer. However, I agree with Simon: do not put things in files that you do not want to have in files.

Answer (score 1):

use onstop override to do that

like this:

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStop();
    if(isFinishing() == true)
    {
        SM.removePreferences();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you're looking for can be achieved using `onSaveInstanceState` mechanism.

Nonetheless, I'll try answering your specific question while assuming that by saying that "the method is never implemented" you mean that the if statement value is always false and that your method doesn't get called.

`isFinishing()` returns `true` only when you called `finish()` on the `Activity` or if someone else has requested that it will be finished. 
If you just click on the home button, you will get `isFinishing()` == `false`, thus your method doesn't gets called. So make sure you're actually finishing the `Activity` and not just pausing it.

Anyways, the best way to find out what's the problem is to use the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Don't save your Fragment's instance state in `SharedPreferences`, but in the Bundle that is meant to do that. You can access it like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if ((savedInstanceState != null) {
        // get your values, for example:
        mID = savedInstanceState.getInt("ID");
    }
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    // put your values, for example:
    outState.putInt("ID", mID);
}
```

This way you don't have to manage the values yourself.

If you have custom Objects, you can make them implement [`Parcelable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html).

In contrast, `SharedPreferences` are meant to save values that should persist even after the application closes, i.e.: preferences.

Comment: I noticed something about using this method, it's not necessarily called.

Comment: Then you should post another question about your specific problem with that.

Answer (score 0):

The better location to do that is onDestroy() without the if statement.
however, you can read from Android documentation about onDestroy() that:

> There are situations where the system will simply kill the activity's hosting process without calling this method (or any others) in it, so it should not be used to do things that are intended to remain around after the process goes away.

So, in my opinion, if you don't want data remains after activity ends, you should use a class to hold it.